# Display date and and id corresponding to maximal third value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in my database as you can see below: Travel, a table which contains informations about drivers, Travel, which contains informations about travels, and DroveBy, a table which displays which driver drove which Ttravel (relation between the ID's). I would like to write a query which returns the ID of a driver, its name, and the date he traveled the most. In the example below, I would like to return:

```
1-Armand-2012-07-18
2-Elish-2012-06-18
3-Armand-2012-07-18.
```

Thanks a lot

[image: Driver]

[image: Travel]

[image: DroveBy]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the `max` of difference between `start_time` and `arrived_time` like below query

```
select d.driver_id, d.name, t.travel_date 
from(
    select dB.driver_id,
    max(timestampdiff(minute,start_time,arrival_time)) maxTime
    from droveBy dB
    join travel t on dB.travel_id = t.travel_id
         group by dB.driver_id)t1
 join travel t on t1.maxTime = timestampdiff(minute,t.start_time,t.arrival_time)
 join droveBy dB on t1.driver_id = dB.driver_id and t.travel_id = dB.travel_id
join Driver d on dB.driver_id = d.driver_id;
```

This gave me below result

[image]

Hope this would help you out.

Comment: I'm interested in return the date at which the time of travel was maximal, you're returning here the maximal date...

Comment: You mean you are expecting the maximum time difference between arrival_time and start_time?